# Pandas df.to.csv saves in the same working directory as opposed to absolute path

Tags: python, pandas

I have two scripts, both parse dataframes to csv files, one saves in ~/Desktop the other one in my current working directory, I need it to save to ~/Desktop

```
summary_file = local_file + ".csv"
series_file = local_file + ".csv"

print("this is the summary to %s" % summary_file)
file = open(summary_file, 'w')
file.write(breakdown)
file.close()

print("this is the full time series to %s" % series_file)
file = open(series_file, 'w')
file.write(df.to_csv())
file.close()
```

Until now I have tried:
file.write(df.to_csv(r'/home//Desktop/')

The result was:
file.close()
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

My OS is Ubuntu 21.04 and I am using Python3

Comment: this would work: `df.to_csv('~/Desktop/afile.csv')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can directly write a pandas DataFrame to a csv by specifying the file with the full path. You don't have to use `open` except when you're writing strings.

Try:

```
#since breakdown is a string, use open()
with open(f"/home/username/Desktop/{summary_file}", "w") as f:
    f.write(breakdown) 

#since df is a DataFrame use to_csv()
df.to_csv(f"/home/username/Desktop/{series_file}")
```

Change the path as necessary.

Comment: OP mentions Ubuntu

Comment: @MDR - I don't see how that would change the logic, especially as I mentioned "change the path as necessary", but edited

Comment: It's fine :).  It's just from the 'level' of the question it would seem that being as specific as possible may help the OP.

Comment: @MDR Python is my weakness, not file paths, but you do have a point.

Comment: @not_speshal your answer is 50% there. df.to_csv worked. now with breakdown.to_csv the output is the following "breakdown.to_csv(f"/home/desktop/{summary_file}")
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'to_csv'"

Comment: print("Writing summary to %s" % summary_file)
    breakdown.to_csv(f"/home/Desktop/{summary_file}")
    #file.write(breakdown)
    #file.close()

Comment: @Gabriel - Okay, so `breakdown` is a string and not a DataFrame. I've edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: @Gabriel, I wasn't judging you beyond the question :o).  It's just a saw a raw string with a double `//` and no file name so I thought the answer could be more specific since you did mention Linux.

Comment: @MDR it's no biggie, I facepalmed myself from 'hiding' my username as if it's not the same as my username here, haha. Anyway, I am here to learn and I hope I can chime in for whoever is more 'noobier' than me.